# ActionBar tabs in a fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I am attempting to make a tablet UI that implements a ViewPager within a ViewPager. I was wondering if there was a simple way to add tabbed navigation at the top of the fragment containing the inner ViewPager. What is the appropriate method to get the tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a starting point:

https://gist.github.com/blackcj/5960698

You'll need a ViewPager, PagerTabStrip and FragmentPagerAdapter in addition to your app Activity and Fragments. The code from the MainActivity in the example can be moved into a Fragment. The PagerTabStrip will give you the navigation across the top.

More information here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: I was unaware of the PagerTabStrip. Thank you!